# Directions parts are not generated in Java (Generated)

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, directions

I'm still an amateur software developer. Directions parts are not generated in Java (Generated) even though I have specified fragmentet actions in Android Studio. So I can't use directions in onOptionsItemSelected. What would be the reason?

[navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDKZ6.png)

[dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9c4v.png)

Comment: you must `rebuild` your app first to generate `Directions` parts.

Comment: I tried the Rebuild and Invalidate Caches options but they didn't work.